# Access and iteration inner objects collection from template Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've a problem, or more probably a misundertanding with variable passed to the template on Meteor.
I want to do something really simple; I've a Collection of articles. Each article have an correspondy inner Tags array.

**template articles**

```
<template name="articles">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 small-centered columns"> 
        {{#each articles}}
        {{> _article}}
        {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**partial _article**

```
<template name="_article">
<div class="article-container small-12 columns">
    <div class="article-header small-12 columns">   
      <h1 class="left">Titre: {{title}}</h1>
      <button class="right delete">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <article class="overview small-12 columns">

          <h2>Categorie: {{nameCateg}}</h2>
          <h2>{{createdAt}}</h2>
          <p>{{content}}</p>
          </article>
          <div class="article-footer small-12 columns">
            <p>Tags: 
            {{#each tags}} // I want to do something like that...
            lbl: {{tag.label}}
            {{/each}}
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

**Inspection on one article with Mongol**

```
{
"_id:" "c47cezerzerz",
"title": "titre,
"tags"[
{"id": "aurtht58",
"label": "tag1"},
{"id": "aurthfe8",
"label": "tag2"}
]
}
```

When I try to iterate with the #each on tags, tags seems to refers to the whole tags collection, not only the inner tags list. How to fix that?

So I've maybe missed something, like the scope of these variables... Actually I don't really know how they work...

Comment: Have you tried `{{#each articles.tags}}`?

Comment: yep, {{#each articles.tags}}
  lbl: {{label}}
  {{/each}} just display nothing, no errors but not event the "lbl: " text. But I think it's normal, articles.tags isn't the full articles array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context inside `{{#each}}` is a child context focused on the document currently being iterated.
For example with the following document:

```
{
  foo : [
    {
      bar : 1
    },
    {
      bar : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

You would use it this way:

```
{{#each foo}}
  <p>bar is : {{bar}} and also {{this.bar}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

So, in your case, directly reference the fields (`{{label}}`, ...)

The lookup is first done on the current template context, then on its helpers, then up and up toward the global helpers.
Template contexts are a whole topic, a good starting point in the [SpaceBars documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md).

Comment: Amen. Thanks a lot, i didn't know that! {{#each}} is a child context focused on the document currently being iterated. It make sense on my mind now! I will read about it, i didn't have the reflex to check the SpaceBars doc...

Answer (score 1):

I think that until you access to the `tags` level, you iterate on a cursor. (to be confirmed). A cursor is obtained with a `collection.find()` if you add a `fetch()`or use `collection.findOne()` you get an array (in your case, you just access an array within your document) and the rules are changing for the spacebar iteration.

You need to access your tags using `{{this}}` and tag items using `{{this.label}}`

Comment: I will read a bit more about it an comfirm that later about the internal mechanism. Ty!